# Angular Material - cannot interpolate pageSize

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use in my application data table from Angular Material https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview.

Default paginator looks like below:

```
<md-paginator #paginator
                    [length]="projectTableDatabase.data.length"
                    [pageIndex]="0"
                    [pageSize]="5"
                    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
      </md-paginator>
```

But I don't want to hardcode pageSize and I tried interpolate this variable:

```
<md-paginator #paginator
                    [length]="projectTableDatabase.data.length"
                    [pageIndex]="0"
                    [pageSize]="{{pageSize}}"
                    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
      </md-paginator>
```

pageSize is a variable in my component with set value.
But now I got an error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{pageSize}}] in ng:///AppModule/MyTableComponent.html@61:20 ("ength]="myTableDatabase.data.length"
                    [pageIndex]="0"
                    [ERROR ->][pageSize]="{{pageSize}}"
                    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
      </md-pagi"):
```

How can I bind pageSize with my variable?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use interpolation, read about property binding

If you user property name with [ ] you have to use name of variable

`[property]="variable"`

without [ ] you can pass hardcoded value

`property="value"` here is possible to use interpolation, example:

`property="{{variable}}"`